# Match route consistently with regex

Tags: php, regex, router

I am creating a simple routing system for personal use. Adding routes goes
something like this:

```
Router::add('/news/?', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'index' ]);
// /news/17, /news/17/, /news/17/a-title-here
Router::add('/news/\d+/?[^/]*', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'show' ]);
Router::add('/news/\d+/edit/?', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'edit' ]);
Router::add('/news/\d+/delete/?', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'delete' ]);
```

The problem is that because the second rule allows for an optional title in the url,
if either "edit" or "delete" do not have a trailing slash in the actual url,
my system calls show() **and** either edit() or delete(), depending on what is in
the url. So, if the url has either "edit" or "delete", no mater whether it contains
the trailing slash, it should just trigger that method, and not show(), which should
only be called when the url contains something like "/news/" or "/news".

To clarify a little more, if I have the url like "/news/17/delete" (no trailing /), it
calls both show() and delete(). However, if the url looks like "/news/17/delete/" (with a
trailing slash), then show() is not called, wich is correct.

Here's the Router class, in case it helps (should I paste it here, just let me know).
https://github.com/FernandoBasso/phprouter/blob/master/helpers/class.Router.php

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who helped. I learned a lot from all the ideas your shared and would accept them all as the answer if I could. :)

Comment: You should process your routes in order, from the most specific to the most generic, and stop as soon as you find a match.

Comment: Why be so flexible in allowing caller to either include or exclude a trailing slash at their discretion?  Why not enforce a single approach to this? Also have you given any thought to actually using HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to determine the action rather than a URI segment?

Comment: That was my first alternative. I did not complete disregard it though. I did not make my mind yet as whether it should enforce a single approach. It has pros and cons. It seems strange to me that a url would cause loading of a "resource" fail because of a missing or extra "/". I'll rethink that. Thanks.

Comment: @moonwave99, What you suggested worked. I actually had a commented "break" statement in the loop that looks for matches. Just placed the edit and delete routes above the 'list' and show ones, and it just worked. Makes all the sense. If you answer the question I'll accept it.

Comment: @MikeBrant, But then how can I send a PUT verb (for instance) from a form that is used to edit a resource?

Comment: @FernandoBasso From your URL styles, it seemed like you were trying to build a RESTful API. Typically, one would not build such an interface and expect to have web forms interacting directly with it, you would rather have a front end web service working with this backend API service, such that all calls against the API would be server to server.  If that is not your intent, you can simply ignore this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should process your routes in order, from the most specific to the most generic, and stop as soon as you find a match, e.g.:

```
Router::add('/news/\d+/edit/?', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'edit' ]);
Router::add('/news/\d+/delete/?', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'delete' ]);
Router::add('/news/\d+/?[^/]*', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'show' ]);
Router::add('/news/?', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'index' ]);
```

This way, when you loop through them, you try to match first the `/news/:id/:action` route.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
Router::add('/news/\d+/?(?!/?(?:edit|delete))[^/]*$', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'show' ]);
```

Comment: I considered that, but discarded it since "edit" and "delete" are words that might appear in a title. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Based on Ed Cottrell's code and yours, I'll consider this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the possibility that the second rule matches edit or delete:

```
Router::add('/news/\d+/?(?!edit/?$|delete/?$)[^/]*', [ 'controller' => 'NewsController', 'method' => 'show' ]);
```

This should work, because it will allow through these examples:

```
/news/12/foo
/news/12/foo-delete
/news/12/delete-foo
```

But not:

```
/news/12/delete
/news/12/delete/
/news/12/edit
/news/12/edit/
```

Comment: Yep, it is very unlikely that a title would contain a single edit or delete word. I'll think over that.

Comment: Well, if it does, it will conflict with your protocol -- how would you trigger an edit or delete of an item titled "delete"?  In other words, you shouldn't allow an item to have the title "edit" or "delete".

Comment: I see. It makes sense.

Comment: If you really want to have items with the title "edit" or "delete", tweak your protocol, so that view-only requests look like `/news/\d+/view/.*` (or similar) -- this would remove any ambiguity.